# Does LINQpad output generated SQL with Entity Framework 6 RTM?

Tags: linqpad, entity-framework-6

When using a LINQpad data connection with an Entity Framework 6 DbContext derived object, I'm not getting anything in the SQL pane. I have no problems running queries or performing updates, just not seeing the generated SQL. According to the release notes: "*LINQpad now provides full SQL traces with EF 6.0 Beta 1 and later*"  I did not use the EF betas, so I can't confirm it was working with that.  I've never had an issue with LINQpad and EF 5. Did something break between the EF 6 Beta and RTM?

I'm using LINQpad Premium version 4.47.02, EF 6 RTM against a SQL 2012 DB.

A data connection using Linq-to-SQL against the same DB populates the SQL pane.

Thanks!
Jeff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet. There was a change in how you register with EF6 to intercept SQL communications between Beta 1 and RTM. This has been fixed with LinqPad V4.47.03 Beta.